# Execute code from external file using Roslyn

Tags: c#, regex, roslyn

I'm using **Roslyn** to execute C# code at runtime.

First I tried this code (which works fine) :

```
engine.Execute(@"System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");");
```

After that, I wanted to execute code from a text file, so I did this :

```
string line;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    engine.Execute(line);
}
```

I copied the string that I used before in a external file called test.txt.

So my test.txt contains the following line : `@"System.Console.Write(""Hello World"");"`

When compliling the code **I get an error** that something is missing.

So I figured out that, it was just the backslash.

And changed the code to this :

```
string line;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string toto = line;
    string titi = toto.Replace(@"\\", @"");

    engine.Execute(toto);
}
```

Now when I run this code, **nothing happens** (no error).

And when I inspect the variables content, I get this :

`toto : "@\"System.Console.Write(\"\"Hello World\"\");\""`

`titi : "@\"System.Console.Write(\"\"Hello World\"\");\""`

Is that normal ! Normally the baskslash should be removed, but it not the case.

What's the problem

`EDIT`

I want to keep the exact string that I passe to Roslyn in code, so don't suggest answers like change the string in the file. Another solutions please !

Comment: Try putting this code in the file: `System.Console.Write("Hello World");`, nothing else. Should work fine.

Comment: What do you mean ? I never heard about that !

Comment: You don't need to escape strings in files. StreamReader does that for you. Just type it like my edited comment.

Comment: @ofstream: That needs to be explained more clearly.  StreamReader does not escape strings.

Comment: @SLaks Where specifically?

Comment: @Schneider: Your file doesn't actually make sense, unless you want to execute not code, but a string literal containing code.

Comment: @Schneider SLaks answer explains it.

Comment: Also, _what does the error say_?

Comment: It's ok now, I copied the code with literal, the thing that I shouldn't do :) Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misunderstanding strings.

`@"..."` is a *string literal*; it creates a string with a value of `...`.

Therefore, when you write `Execute(@"System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");")`, the actual value that you pass to `Execute()` is `System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`

When you read a string from a file, you get the actual value of the string.
`StreamReader` does not assume that the file contains a C# string literal expression (that would be extremely weird, unexpected, and useless).

Therefore, when you read a file containing the text `@"System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");"`, you get a string with the actual value `@"System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");"`.
(to write this in a string literal, you would need to write `@"@""System.Console.WriteLine(""""Hello World"""");""""`)

When you then pass that string to Roslyn's `Execute()` method, Roslyn evaluates the string literal expression, and returns the string value of the literal.